# ActionCable displays an empty page after action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm following Michael Hartl [tutorial](https://www.learnenough.com/action-cable-tutorial#sec-the_room_channel) about Rails 5 ActionCable, to build a simple chat, and a problem is occurring inside my `create` action in `MessageController`:

```
  def create
    message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
    if message.save
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel',
                                     content:  message.content,
                                     username: message.user.username
      head :ok
    end
  end
```

It goes until `head :ok`, and after that, display an empty HTML page. The log is:

```
Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h9UsB78aX8mO8Nyn8eZEUuDzAOxL4V7UCMwNuTfwALliMv7OCkcUIeR4/xXIcvPjwq9H1bphjn6G96G+0VYisw==", "message"=>{"content"=>"oi"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Message Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 50]]
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (9.3ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "oi"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", 2016-09-19 02:12:58 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-19 02:12:58 UTC]]
   (9.1ms)  commit transaction
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to room_channel: {:content=>"oi", :username=>"alice"}
Completed 200 OK in 69ms (ActiveRecord: 22.0ms)


RoomChannel transmitting {"content"=>"oi", "username"=>"alice"} (via streamed from room_channel)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-09-19 02:12:58 +0000
RoomChannel stopped streaming from room_channel
```

(After that, I can refresh the page and the message is displayed properly)

Why that is happening?

My RoomChanel class:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "room_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

end
```

My room.coffee

```
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create "RoomChannel",
connected: ->
  # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

disconnected: ->
  # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

received: (data) ->
  alert data.content
```

Comment: I finished the tutorial. Whel, that doesn't answer my question of "why" that happens, but my advice for someone else who is with the same trouble is: remove `head :ok`. Aparently it's unecessary, because if I add a test whit `assert_response :success` to the action, it'll pass.

Comment: I suggest you add this as an answer, rather than a comment, so that it can be upvoted, is more visible, etc. This worked for me, too.

Comment: Good to know, @EdRuder . Answer added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a sugestion, I'm adding as answer what I did to get around this problem. It doesn't answer why that happens, but solve the problem.

The solution is: remove `head :ok`.

Aparently it's unecessary, because if I add a test whit `assert_response :success` to the action, it'll pass.

Comment: This returns 'No template found for MessagesController#create, rendering head :no_content' for me, unfortunately. It doesn't show the usual white screen but it seems like the button isn't doing anything. If i refresh though, the message is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is accepted already, but this solution worked for me without having to remove `head :ok`, maybe it helps somebody out.

Normally in the development environment people are running `localhost:3000` but i was running on a different port, `localhost:3030`.

And this case i had to add an allowed request origin for that port, like so:

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [
      'http://localhost:3030'
  ]
```

to my `/config/environments/development.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I'm following Michael's tutorial for ActionCable and had the same problem.
I think this was due to the format of the form partial `_anything.html.erb`.

```
app/views/messages/_message_form.html
```

As you go through the tutorial, you're upgrading to Action Cable features. But in the `_message_form` partial, it is still with the usual `HTTP request`. So after you broadcast a message using the `messages_controller.rb`, the browser render an empty page because the form was already rendered.

`app/views/messages/_message_form.html`, Originally:

```
<div class="message-input">
  <%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So, you have to add the `remote: true` to the form, like this:

```
<div class="message-input">
  <%= form_for(@message, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Adding the `remote: true` makes an JS request (Ajax, in this case)

Quoting Michael:

> You can verify by submitting a message that it appears as desired, but in
> fact this is a cheat because the form from Listing 6 is currently submitting
> an ordinary `HTTP POST` request, which causes the page to refresh. In order
> to use Action Cable, we need to change the form to submit a remote request
> that submits an Ajax request without refreshing the page. We can do this by
> including the `remote: true` option in the call to `form_for`.

Note that I'm doing everything in localhost:3000